# I want to know why the error occurred in the following code. Is it related to the type conversion operator？

Tags: c++, c++17, clang++

I want to know why the error occurred in the following code. I use `clang-17` for compilation. Compiling this code using `gcc11.4.0` will also result in an error message
I guess it should be related to the type conversion operator, but I cannot pinpoint the specific reason。

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    template <class _Ty>
    explicit operator _Ty() const  noexcept
    {
        return c;
    }

    std::string c = "sdafasd";
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    const std::string &str = static_cast<const std::string &>(std::move(a));
}
```

I change the code to the following so that there will be no errors：

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    template <class _Ty>
    explicit operator _Ty&() const  noexcept
    {
        return c;
    }

    std::string c = "sdafasd";
};
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: what error? Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Questions about a compiler error must include a [mcve] and the complete compiler error message in the question.

Comment: the code you did include in the question will cause compiler errors because you forgot to include `<string>`. In both versions of the code

Comment: there is actually an instersting question here, but you need to [edit] to add the missing information

Comment: Why the `std::move`?  That doesn't do anything useful in that context.  Could just do `auto const& str = a.operator std::string();`

Comment: Side note: names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_Ty`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of how template argument deduction is specified (see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Conversion_function_template, [Implications of conversion function template argument deduction in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39150553/5754656)), `_Ty` isn't normally deduced as a reference type.

It's a similar logic as to why with `template<typename T> void f(T x);`, `T x` won't be deduced as a reference type.

Calling it manually will have the expected type:

```cpp
const std::string &str = std::move(a).operator const std::string&();
```

But otherwise, to be able to convert to a reference type, you need to have `&`.